# Unable to use a matlab function

Tags: function, matlab

I wanted to move from one point to other on a spherical earth, and when I looked up, I found there is a function named [`reckon`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/map/ref/reckon.html) in matlab that does exactly what I need. But when I call it, it says `Undefined function 'reckon' for input arguments of type 'double`. Which means that maybe the function is not in my library. So I found the m-file from the internet and tried, but then it leads to same error with a different function, which I found the function `reckon` depends on. So I included that in my folder too, and then again there is a new function missing... and so on.

I have Matlab R2011b.

These functions seem to be in-built matlab functions as they show up in help, but as I'm new to matlab, maybe I'm wrong. What can be done?

Comment: That's not a "built-in" MATLAB function. It's actually from the Mapping Toolbox, which you don't seem to have.

Comment: @Li-aung Yip - Thanks..how can i add the toolbox? I just want to use the reckon function.

Comment: It's not free, if that's what you're asking. See http://www.mathworks.com.au/products/mapping/ .

Answer (score 4):

As i just wanted to use the functions of the Mapping Toolbox,after some looking up, i found them all in a single package on a website. If any body else wants them too, and don't have the mapping toolbox, you can get all the functions here.

http://mooring.ucsd.edu/software/matlab/doc/toolbox/geo/index.html